# Designing a Nodejs WebApp

Tags: node.js, web-applications, socket.io, http-caching

I'm currently working on building out a webapp to display a real-time dashboard for remote machinery. I'm trying to implement the system using Nodejs and I was hoping to get come critique for my ideas on how to implement it.

The app is going to have two main goals:

1.) Display the state of the machinery in real-time, updating it about once every minute or so

2.) Saving the state of the machine to a database every 15 minutes.

In order to access the data, I need to make API requests to a third party vendor to pull the data from their database. I need to make about 6 requests per machine, and by the end of the year I'll have to support about 20 machines at a time. Taking that together, I'll need to make around 120 requests per minute to keep up-to-date information on the machinery.

The users who are using the webapp will only be able to see a subset of the machines when they logon. However, some machines will be shared between different users, so rather than replicating the API calls for users looking at the same machine at the same time, I'd rather build a cache of all the machine data that I refresh once every minute and then only send each user the portion of the data that's relevant to them. Also, this is convenient for the data logging purpose because when I want to save the data I just have to save the entire cache.

One concern I have is being able to complete the data-fetching API requests in time for the data to be re-displayed. I know that I can gather the data in parallel calls using the async library, but I'm concerned that the requests won't finish in time before it's time to generate a second update, causing requests to build up. One option is that I can just let each api request send its data to the front-end independent of the other requests, but I'd like to be able to update everything in batches.

Another question I have in building the system is whether socket.io would be a useful resource for my needs. I know that the library helps you generate real time apps, which is what I need to do, but from what I've read, socket.io seems designed for sharing all updates beet all users rather than just sending partial updates to each user. Rather than using socket.io to send server-driven updates, I could add some code in the front-end of my app to request an update on a regular interval. Using this solution means I could also have each client simply request the data that they need. However, I'm still curious as to whether the library could offer anything that could be useful in developing this project.

My last concern has to do with scaling the application. After the end of the year, I'll need to monitor more and more machines, and with each one that's added, the amount of data I need to grab and store goes up too. If anyone has any recommendations on how can get started early on design the system to scale well, I'd like to hear it.

I appreciate any feedback. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you use a redis box as you cache storage. You can have a master node instance take care of the necessary requests, save the results to redis, and have all the necessary node sub-instances pull the latest info from redis very fast. Additionally, redis has pub/sub capabilities that will allow you to broadcast to all instances that there is new data, so each instance can fetch it and push it through a websocket to your UI without requiring further refreshes from your users.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot address all the point raised but I would:

1 - use socket.io

which allows data to be "emitted" from client to server and vice versa. The server can broadcast data to all clients or to one specific client.

I would research how socket.io scales.

Note NGINX works great with socket.io

2 - If it's acceptable I would recommend a Dockerised solution. Docker allows you to containerise your solution. For example your Docker container would container your web server and the files to be served. This gives a complete separation of concerns. Also you can easily push and pull your solution to docker (think of pushing and pulling VMs).

Pulling your solution from anywhere in a container makes deployment so easy.

Note that Docker is amazing for scaling. You can create a base image - e.g. a stateless web server - then from that image bring up 3 separate Docker containers. Bung a load balancer in front of them and just add more containers when you want.

Answer (score 0):

Good answers from @danday74...

Restarting now, I would:

- Use something like Meteor or [Feathers.Js](http://feathersjs.com/) for a real-time, rest-enabled, scalable base.
- Use [JWT](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) for authentication, as it is easily ported, tested and scalable.
- Use an easily scalable platform provider with easy deployment, like DigitalOcean, Azure, Heroku, etc. **Dokku** on DigitalOcean is particularly potent!

Comment: I recommend Feathers.js, which has a simple and very flexible design based upon Express and Socket.io. You also might consider [Framework7](http://framework7.io/) for the client side.